# "Borgo murattiano": what does it mean?

Tags: word-meaning

Could somebody give me the meaning of "murattiano", which I encountered in this paragraph from Gianrico Carofiglio's book, *Né qui né altrove*?

> La vista di Bari arrivando da sud, di notte, è la mia  preferita. C'è il mare, scuro ma non minaccioso, c'è la linea del lungomare e poi del porto, piena di luci e promesse, ci sono gli edifici più alti, la torre della Provincia, il campanile della cattedrale di San Sabino, il grattacielo della Motta, construito dove un tempo esisteva la prima casa del **Borgo murattiano** - che danno ritmo alla silhouetta della città, ci sono i lampioni di ghisa e gli zampolli nel mare. Tutto, entrando da quella parte, comunica un senso di piccola metropoli, cordiale e accogliente. È bello.

Comment: It is simply the name of a neighborhood of the city: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murat_%28quartiere_di_Bari%29

Comment: It's "murattiano" or "muratiano"?

Comment: From a cursory Google search both forms seem to be used (it is named after Joachim Murat). I know no more

Comment: First of all, it's "murattiano"  and secondly, if it's just a name or it's named after Joachim Murat, should't it be capitalized?

Comment: No, @Vic: in Italian, adjective derived from proper names are in general not capitalised: “i temi manzoniani”, “la geometria riemanniana” e così via.

Comment: As for doubling the consonant, @Charo, I don't know this particular adjective, but it was not unusual to double them in adjectives from foreign names, even when in the original no double letter was present: for instance, [*volterriano*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/volterriano/) from Voltaire, and even (rarely) [*nicciano*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nicciano/) from Nietzsche.

Comment: @DaG: I asked that because at the Wikipedia article cited by Denis it's written "muratiano".

Comment: @Charo: If Italian Wikipedia says so, then probably the correct form is with a double T.

Comment: so it's the first house of the village Murat, isn't it?

Comment: @DaG Wikipedia seems inconsistent about that (in the article I linked the form *muratiano* is used, but in the article about the city of Bari you can find *murattiano* instead). I was unable to find any definitive reference and unless someone living there chimes in I'll assume they are alternative forms.

Comment: @DenisNardin I've always seen *murattiano*

Answer (score 4):

**Murattiano**: adjective from "of Murat":

[Gioacchino Murat.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joachim_Murat)

I'm from Bari, I can tell you we speak and write it "Murattiano", with two 'T'.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Marco! For completeness, I think you shoud also explain in your answer that "Borgo murattiano" is the name of a neighborhood of Bari.